# ?New Domain, new index.php file... how do I link the two?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, dns, hosting

I know this is going to be a VERY basic question for you to answer, but I just can't find the answer anywhere. I'm probably searching the wrong terms.

So I have a GoDaddy hosting account, with a domain, and a running Wordpress website - no issues there!

I just bought a new domain and would like to have a couple of pages without using Wordpress. However I'm not quite sure how to link the index.php file to the new domain.

Below in the code in my index.php and have placed it in my root directory next to where the folder for my other site is.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
 <html>
     <head>
      <title>PHP Test</title>
     </head>
     <body>
     <?php echo '<p>Hello World</p>'; ?> 
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Off topic. Not a programming question. Server/DNS configuration is not a programming issue.

Comment: As @MarcB Said, also i think you putting your `index.php` in your home root(out of `public_html`)

Comment: Sorry if I posted in the wrong area. Yes the file in in public_html how on earth to I link it to the new domain?

Comment: if not then post more information to get anyone to help you as you provide very low details, does your new domain working? what error/msg you get? what result you got and what you was expecting?

Comment: It's a very simple question. I just want a new website with a new domain. 

Can I do this in the same root directory or do I need a new one altogether?

I just can't find the information anywhere. Plenty of tutorials will teach you how to write a index.html/php script, but they don't tell you what to do with it.

Comment: lol, next time you replying on a comment do @username otherwise that user will never know you answered him, and about your question, **yes** you can do that with the same root, but you need to activate the new domain NameServers with your hosting NameServer, usually ns1 and ns2.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved. I hadn't added the new domain in my Cpanel.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the header by using $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] and then doing a simple if or switch statement for redirect.

```
       <?php 

        $domain = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

        if ($domain == 'test.com') {

            header('Location: http://test.com/NewSite');

        } else {

            header('Location: http://test.com/wordpress');

        }

        ?>
```